# Triple DES Decryption of plain text

Tags: xor, encryption, des

I have some plain text encrypted with Triple XOR and then Triple DES. I also have the key. How do I manage to uncover the plain text?

Comment: Which language? If you don't want to do it programmatically this is off-topic on SO.

Comment: Triple XOR, all rounds with the same key?

Comment: While you are adding the language, you may as well add the type of XOR encryption and the encryption mode and padding mode for the Tripple DES cipher.

Comment: Yeah it's all with the same key. And I'd be happy to do it with any language. All i know about it is what I've stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a handy tool: [Online decrypt tool](http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/decrypt/)

Comment: I tried that first, I just ended up getting random symbols out of it.